# Line up x-axis with tick marks in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

How can I properly line up the x-axis values to the vertical lines in the chart? Currently they are not properly aligned.

```
var data = [
  {
    "due": 89.99, 
    "datestr": "2012-12-01 00:00:00", 
    "paid": 89.99
  }, 
  {
    "due": 89.99, 
    "datestr": "2013-01-01 00:00:00", 
    "paid": 101.25
  }, 
  {
    "due": 109.99, 
    "datestr": "2013-02-01 00:00:00", 
    "paid": 143.69
  }, 
  {
    "due": 109.99, 
    "datestr": "2013-03-01 00:00:00", 
    "paid": 130.65
  }, 
  {
    "due": 139.99, 
    "datestr": "2013-04-01 00:00:00", 
    "paid": 150.25
  },

  {
    "due": 149.99, 
    "datestr": "2013-05-01 00:00:00", 
    "paid": 139.99
  },
  {
    "due": 149.99, 
    "datestr": "2013-06-01 00:00:00", 
    "paid": 139.99
  },
  {
    "due": 89.99, 
    "datestr": "2013-07-01 00:00:00", 
    "paid": 139.99
  }
];




//Load values into new arrays

var amtDue = new Array();
var amtPaid = new Array();

for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
  amtDue[i] = data[i].due;
  amtPaid[i] = data[i].paid;
}

// Margins, width and height. 
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 60, left: 50},
    width = 1000,
    height = 400,
    padding = 100;

// Scales.
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var due = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
var paid = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);


//Domains
x.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.date; }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.date;})]);
y.domain([50, 300]);
due.domain([0, amtDue.length]);
paid.domain([0, amtPaid.length]);

// Construct our SVG object.
var svg = d3.select(".system-efficiency").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// X-axis MONTHS.
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("top")
    .tickSize(-height)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b'));
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(100," + 0 + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

//X-axis Due Date
var dDate = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(due)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickSize(0)
    .tickFormat(function(d, i) {return amtDue[i];});
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "damount axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(100," + (height) + ")")
    .call(dDate);

//X-axis Paid Date
var pDate = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(paid)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickSize(0)
    .tickFormat(function(d, i) {return amtPaid[i];});
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "pamount axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(100," + (height+20) + ")")
    .call(pDate);

//Y-axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickSize(0);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + ",0)")
    .call(yAxis);

// Date parsing.
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate.parse(d.datestr);
  d.close = +d.close;
});

// Set scale domains. 
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
//y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.due; })]);

// Call x-axis. 
d3.select(".x.axis")
    //.transition().duration(1000)
    .call(xAxis);


// Draw bars for amount due. 
var bars = svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data, function(d) { return d.datestr; });

bars.exit().remove();

// bars.transition().duration(1000)
//     .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
//     .attr("width", width / data.length)
//     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.due); })
//     .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.due);});

bars.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "duebar")
    .attr("width", width/data.length)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {  return i * (width / data.length); })
    .attr("y", height)
    .attr("height", 0)
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.due); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return (y(d.due)+3)-y(d.due);});



// Line function.
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.paid); });


// Draw line. 
 svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
```

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keturp/df00fyuu/3/).

Comment: Here is the fiddle showing example
http://jsfiddle.net/keturp/df00fyuu/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/hbmwbnx6/

Using your current approach, this is sort-of-fixable. To start with, you have 8 data values (Dec '12 to July '13). Using the `d3.time.scale()` with that date domain will give you 8 'month' tick, but a scale divided into 7 equal 'gaps' between the ticks.

So for the `d3.scale.linear()` scales to line up, you should use:

```
due.domain([0, amtDue.length - 1]);
```

rather than:

```
due.domain([0, amtDue.length]);
```

because the array length counts from 1, not 0.

Also note that from your code I removed several horizontal `translate`'s.

The reason I say this is only a sort-of-fix, is that the bars for "amount due" don't line up correctly with the months. That's because the bar widths are equal (using `.attr("width", width/(data.length -1))`) but months (on the `d3.time` scale) are not of equal length:

[image: mis-aligned bars]

The solution to this would be to use the `x` (time) scale to define the bar width

**Update**

Here's an update of the fiddle with a (slightly hacky) solution to the bar width issue by taking the current date and previous date values from the data: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/hbmwbnx6/1/

Code is:

```
// The first date from your data - don't hardcode!
var previousdate = new Date("2012-12-01 00:00:00")

bars.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "duebar")
    .attr("width", function(d, i) { 
        widthval = x(d.date) - (x(previousdate));
        previousdate = d.date;
        return widthval;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { 
        xval = x(previousdate);
        previousdate = d.date;
        console.log(previousdate);
        return xval;
    })
    ...
```

Note that this code highlights another issue: Bars appear to show data between 2 dates, but actually show data at a specific point in time. The December '12 'amount due' value isn't shown, while the Jan '13 value is shown *as the bar between Dec and Jan* in your chart. You'd need to decide how you wanted to display this

Comment: I see what you are saying.  Appreciate the help, Thanks!

Comment: I tried the following but didnt seem to resolve the problem.
`var due = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);`

Comment: Just updated the answer (and added new fiddle link) with an example of how you could calculate the 'amount due' bar `width` and `x` using the date and `x` scale, but you may want to improve it a little!

Comment: for your x domain you can simplify it by saying: `x_domain=d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; });`